# Appgyver $http resource angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, resources, steroids

I've been developing in AngularJS (MEANstack using Yeoman Generator/Bower/Grunt) now for about six months. I just discovered Appgyver so I thought it would be a great opportunity to 'move' the front-end from the browser to a hybrid app for my mobile users.

I am super confused by something that I presume is ***very basic.***

How do I use the Angular resources like $http?

My goal is to 're-use' the Node/Express side of my App as a REST client and the Appgyver app will get it's data from there.

***Potentially Helpful Details:*** I've followed the Appgyver Docs and been able to create a Data Resource in *their cloud* and import that using the Supersonic methods. Perhaps this is the only way to do it?

I'm hoping that I can use the traditional $http services so that I can customize my URL calls within my controller instead of on their third party portal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppGyver dev here! There's nothing special to it – you use $http (or any other XHR-wrapping service) as you would in a desktop Angular app. Supersonic Data just leverages our cloud data service and gives a nice promise/stream-based API.

Comment: Thank you sir!! 

My issue was related to CORS on the RESTful server...total newby mistake. :)